# In CrafterCMS, RTE deletes some html tags without inner text

Tags: java, rte, crafter-cms

In **CrafterCMS**, in a content type, I have a field type **RTE**,

If I use the source option and write following code:

```
<p><span>Test</span></p>
<div class="item_icon"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i></div>
```

after update it and be back the code is

```
<p><span>Test</span></p>
```

(last part was deleted)

Is this the expected behavior? can it be changed by configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Crafter team is working on an upgrade of TinyMCE in Crafter CMS 3.0, see here: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/793

If you need a fix right away, you can try to use "&nbsp", or use a tag with: "display:none" for example: `<span style="display:none">Something</span>`